# Verify that the harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)$ is actually harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

This is from the complex analysis written by Gamelin,
given a function $u(x,y)$ that is harmonic,
follow Gamelin's argument, we found its harmonic conjugate
$ v(x, y) = \int_{y_0}^{y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)dt - \int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(s,y_0) + C$
how to verify that $v(x,y)$ is actually harmonic?

I know we can prove this by showing that $f = u+iv$ is analytic,
but I can't prove that $\partial v / \partial x = -\partial u / \partial y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Leibniz rule for differentiating under the integral sign, and the FTC, we have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y) &= \int_{y_0}^y \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) \, dt - \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y_0) \\
&= \int_{y_0}^y -\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}(x,t) \, dt - \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y_0)\tag{$u$ is harmonic} \\
&= -\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)
\end{align}
where in the last line I used the FTC (or it's corollary, or the second FTC whatever you wanna call it) again.

Comment: i Forgot that $u$ is harmonic!!! thanks